# Issue with Polyglossia hyphenation

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, languages, polyglossia

This is my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\disablehyphenation % <-- if I remove this line the word "corrispondente" is not automatically hyphened

\setmainlanguage{italian} % <-- commenting out this line to properly use manual hyphenation

\begin{document}

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon\-dente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon-\linebreak{}dente al genere.}

\bigskip

\today % <-- if you comment out the previous line this line is not properly formatted

\end{document}
```

I compiled it with

```bash
latexmk -lualatex ./foo.tex
```

on TexLive2023 updated.

The first `\parbox` is correctly composed with hyphenation disabled: the word "approssimativamente" is not hyphened. Then in the second `\parbox` I manually hyphened the word. Up to now everything works correctly. But when I tried to do the same thing with the word "corrispondente", it doesn't work.
I found two solution:

- commenting out `\setmainlanguage{italian}` but `\today`'s output is not more translated and formatted in Italian style, or
- create a fake hyphenation using `-\linebreak{}` but I find this solution horrible.

Any ideas?

## Update

I tried to add `\finalhyphendemerits=0` like David suggested to me. Everything works. But my goal is to use Beamer class not article. I did the same and it doesn't work as shown in this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[right]{PaloAlto}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\disablehyphenation

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}

\setmainlanguage{italian}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item foo
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item {\finalhyphendemerits=0
                    Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon\-dente al genere.}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I suspect that `column` environment is not a paragraph and for this reason `\finalhyphendemerits=0` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

By default there is a high penalty (demerits) for having a hyphen on the penultimate line of a paragraph. So there is a lower cost to stretching the space if you lower the  `\finalhyphendemerits` then it chooses hyphenation at that point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\disablehyphenation % <-- if I remove this line the word "corrispondente" is not automatically hyphened

\setmainlanguage{italian} % <-- commenting out this line to properly use manual hyphenation

\begin{document}

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon\-dente al genere.}

\bigskip

new

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{
\finalhyphendemerits=0
Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon\-dente al genere.}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{Rimuovere appros\-simativamente la direzione corrispon-\linebreak{}dente al genere.}

\bigskip

\today % <-- if you comment out the previous line this line is not properly formatted

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated my answer because this solution it seem not working with Beamer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `\finalhyphendemerits`, as shown by David. But I propose a different strategy, namely to add

```
\finalhyphendemerits=0
```

to the definition of `\sloppy`. Under `\sloppy` the paragraphs are already arbitrarily bad, at least this allows for them being a bit less bad.

On the other hand, ragged right seems best in case of very narrow columns and the modified `\sloppy` even allows for a better result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for the second box

\setmainlanguage{italian}

\AddToHook{cmd/sloppy/before}{\finalhyphendemerits=0 }

\begin{document}

\today

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{%
  Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.%
}

\bigskip

\parbox{.25\textwidth}{%
  \RaggedRight
  Rimuovere approssimativamente la direzione corrispondente al genere.%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For reference, this is what's obtained without the patch to `\sloppy`.

[image]